# Exact Meaning: An appalled silence

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> Appalled by the Cambridge dictionary means: "*having strong feelings of
> shock or disapproval*". On the other hand, it also means: "*horrified*".

There exists some ambiguity for me about the *exact* meaning of: **an appalled silence**.

Does it mean:

- *A silence together with fear and distress*
- *A silence resulting from a shock* (possibly as a natural result of a shock)

What does it mean exactly?

Comment: What do you consider to be the two possible meanings?

Comment: Obviously, this is a transferred usage, the classic _transferred epithet_. 'Silence' is not a sentient agent, so can't be 'appalled' in the primary sense any more than a day can be 'proud' in 'It was a proud day for her parents'. Since it's not a very common pairing, you can't decide between your two readings (both make sense and 'apply' – as with the more usual 'stunned silence'). Is it helpful to try to ultra-analyse here? _X happened. This appalled the people present. They were speechless._

Answer (score 2):

*There was an appalled silence* usually implies that the people present were so horrified by something that had just happened that no-one could say anything. I suppose that is your second definition, but I don't consider that the two are mutually exclusive.